# How to make one HTML column be certain width and other be rest of the screen?

Tags: html

Lets say I have a HTML table where the first column includes titles and second column random text(random length):

> ```
> First row                          stuff
> This is a very long title          more stuff
> Third row                          even more stuff
> ```

I would like to have the whole table width to be 100% but the first column width should be as long as the longest title is (lets say 50px) and the second column width should fill the rest of the 100%.

That is because this will be in template that will be sent as an email and the table should look good from different screen sizes but the first column should be as long as the longest title.

I dont want that the long title will be cutted into two lines

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Try looking into [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

and i think if you put an id to your columns you can CSS it after.